How to add a new tab in an eclipse based application
So I have an eclipse RCP based application.
I have created a handler which searches a word and shows it in the "search" tab which is inbuilt in the eclipse.
This is the code for the handler :
`public class ReferencesSearchHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        if (window != null) {
            IStructuredSelection selection = HandlerUtil.getCurrentStructuredSelection(event);
            if (selection != null && !selection.isEmpty()) {
                Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
                if (firstElement instanceof IFile) {
                    IFile file = (IFile) firstElement;
                    IPath path = file.getFullPath();
                    String[] segments = path.segments();
                    String fileNameWithExtension = file.getName();
                    String fileNameWithoutExtension = removeFileExtension(fileNameWithExtension);
                    String searchText = createSearchText(segments, fileNameWithoutExtension);
                    performSearch(searchText);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String createSearchText(String[] segments, String fileNameWithoutExtension) {
        String packageName = segments[2];
        int i = 3;
        int n = segments.length - 1;
        for (i = 3; i < n; i++) {
            packageName = packageName + "." + segments[i];
        }

        return packageName + "." + fileNameWithoutExtension;
    }

    private String removeFileExtension(String fileName) {
        int lastDotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (lastDotIndex > 0) {
            return fileName.substring(0, lastDotIndex);
        }
        return fileName;
    }

    private void performSearch(String projectName) {
        FileTextSearchScope scope = createWorkspaceScope();
        NewSearchUI.runQueryInBackground(new FileSearchQuery(projectName, false, false, scope));
    }

    private FileTextSearchScope createWorkspaceScope() {
        IProject[] projects = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();
        IResource[] resources = new IResource[projects.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
            resources[i] = projects[i];
        }
        return FileTextSearchScope.newSearchScope(resources, new String[] { "*" }, false);
    }

}
`

Now , I don't want to show the search results in the search tab. I want to create a new tab named as "References" and want to show this search result in that tab. Is it even possible ? if so how can I do the same.
Please help.

NewSearchUI.runQueryInBackground always shows results in a "page" in the Search view, so no it is not possible with the standard search.

any other way to collect the search result(other than NewSearchUI) and show in new view?

Only by writing your own code duplicating the parts of NewSearchUI you need - the source is readily available. Note that Java search references just uses a page in the normal search view.
